# Minecraft Script that will remember all the items each person in the server has

Tags: php, gzip, decode, minecraft

I have a minecraft server, and need to backup all the items people have, I hope to do this by editing the .dat files in world/players. In this file, there are .dat files and their names are the usernames of each player. when I open it with Notepad++, it shows me gibberish like this:

[image: When Opened in NPP]

Regular Notepad gives me this:

````
‹       ãb``bà
ÎIM-ÉÌM-b`àd`óÍ/ÉÌÏcc```¶ÛqæÀÉEÚ“öob=Ô£i×ý‰Ù5S  #‡ž{Q~i^
#‡GiQ   H?È46ÔÄœ’Œÿÿ™8]€byÅ@Ã€f¥˜3‹u88=óÊRóJò‹*AœÌùÅ`û˜Û„¥<^$çà ’apˆßñM&ðÐ‘Ž%%    ‰ÉÙ[€ÖƒÝœ™—4–Å-³(õÿV·Äœ—Ìâ’Ä¼äTˆÉAù%‰ ï°‚\pð²±’ïÌ9L@§¥&–d€M“d  íl+
````

I heard the file is Gzipped. Is this why it is like this? How can I decode this so I can actually read it. I need to decrypt this from a PHP script.

Comment: Someone please explain why there is a negative vote. First, this guy abusing his powers edits my picture and adds stupid things to it, and useless tags, now someone negative voted it. Why are people hating on me so much. Im just a guy who needs help. *sigh*

Comment: sorry, I was trying my new Chrome plugin and I thought it will edit it locally. But trust me, downvote came after. First thing is, did you try to ungzip it in your PC? No. So try it and then ask

Comment: You would need to find out what format the .dat has been saved in, which for some versions is easier said then done.

Comment: @genesis Exactly why I asked. Why are you talking to me like that? What method of gzip would you recommend? Instead of being sour you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: @Qasim: what about http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/unzip.htm ? 5 seconds of google http://www.google.com/search?q=how+ungzip+in+windows

Comment: @genesis Okay Im sorry. Jeez why are people so mean to me today :(

Comment: @genesis your link doesnt work .It says Zip archive, this is a dat file

Comment: @canadiancreed By looking here http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/dat it is the minecraft category. Im not sure what it means, could you help me out?

Comment: @Qasim: Downvotes happens everyday, don't worry. BTW, did you really report me? :p

Comment: Notepad, eh? Have you heard the term hexeditor? Reverse-engineering binary formats is off topic anyway (= go ask the vendor), but you could have at least tried `gzdecode` or `gzip` and shown something workable. Because pasting gibberish output here isn't helpful for the question, hence whoever downvoted: warranted.

Comment: @mario I am not experienced with decoding Gzip, I just tried gzdecode and gzip on my Windows PC, both came up with a semi-decoded string (comment on the first answer below). Looks like it will be a long night of finding out the decryption method of this dat file :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find out what compression it is really but try and open the file with this (gzip):

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('compress.zlib://yourfile.dat', 'r');
if( $fp ){
    while(!feof($fp) ){
        echo fread($fp, 2048);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php for more info.

EDIT:
You may want to try this:

```
<?php
$dat = file_get_contents('yourfile.dat');
echo gzdecoder($dat);

function gzdecoder($d){
    $f=ord(substr($d,3,1));
    $h=10;$e=0;
    if($f&4){
        $e=unpack('v',substr($d,10,2));
        $e=$e[1];$h+=2+$e;
    }
    if($f&8){
        $h=strpos($d,chr(0),$h)+1;
    }
    if($f&16){
        $h=strpos($d,chr(0),$h)+1;
    }
    if($f&2){
        $h+=2;
    }
    $u = gzinflate(substr($d,$h));
    if($u===FALSE){
        $u=$d;
    }
    return $u;
}
?>
```

Also its not `encrypted`, its `compressed`. ;-)

Comment: That will read ` SleepTimer Motion>¸ÌÀÉ¢+’¿´Â\)>‹òEo²tOnGroundHurtTimeHealthÿÿ DimensionAir,  Inventory PosÀ7` Which it clearly seems like it did decode some. How could I possibly find out what type of decryption is it? Could you point me in the right direction?